# C# compare input with keywords

Tags: c#, compare

ive got the following c# code:

```
string textBoxInput = richTextBox1.Text;
                StreamReader SentencesFile = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Jeroen\Desktop\School\C#\opwegmetcsharp\answersSen.txt");
                string Sentence = SentencesFile.ReadLine();
                List<List<string>> keywordsList = new List<List<string>>();
                List<string> outputSentence = new List<string>();

                while (Sentence != null)
                {
                    string keywords = Sentence.Substring(0, Sentence.IndexOf(' '));
                    string sentenceString = Sentence.Substring(0, Sentence.IndexOf(' ') +1);
                    List<string> splitKeyword = keywords.Split(',').ToList();
                    keywordsList.Add(splitKeyword);
                    outputSentence.Add(sentenceString);
                }
                int similar = 0;
                int totalSimilar = 0;
                List<string> SplitUserInput = textBoxInput.Split(' ').ToList();
```

And a .txt file which contains the following:

```
car,bmw Do you own a BMW?
car,Tesla Do you own a Tesla?
new,house Did you buy a new house?
snow,outside Is it snowing outside?
internet,down Is your internet down?
```

I can't figure out how i can compare every word that a user typed in the input (richTextBox1.Text) with the keywords in the .txt file ( like car and bmw for the first sentence )
And it also has to remember the sentence that has the highest amount of "hits".
I'm really stuck and searched a lot, but somehow i can't find out how i can do this.

A lot of thanks in advance!

Comment: There's also a current issue. It runs out of memory because of: List<string> splitKeyword = keywords.Split(',').ToList();

Comment: It's not easy task to implement search algorithm like this. Refer third party algorithms like google search appliances (GSA)

Comment: Erm... You do not need an advanced algorithm to simply compare words in lists...

Comment: Its indeed shouldn't be that hard, because its for 1st year students. But it's too hard atm for me i guess, because I can't seen to figure it out :c

Comment: Change your line with the textbox to : List<string> SplitUserInput = textBoxInput.Text.Split(' ').ToList(); When you say 'the sentence with the highest number of hits' do you mean you want to count the number of times any word entered by the user is counted within each sentence in the textfile? Then you want to display the sentence with the highest count?

Comment: @wentimo Exactly, thats what I mean with 'the sentence with the highest number of hits' (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the LINQ `Contains` to check if a word is found in a list. But beware because it is case sensitive as password does. Use it like this:

```
//assuming you already list the keyword here
List<string> keywords = new List<string>() { "keyword1", "keyword2" };
```

Then for each sentence, supposing in this form:

```
string sentence1 = "Hi, this keYWord1 present! But quite malformed";
string sentence2 = "keywoRD2 and keyWOrd1 also present here, malformed";
```

Note: the above sentences could be your text from `RichTextBox` or file, it doesn't matter. Here I only show the concept.

You can do:

```
string[] words = sentence1.ToLower().Split(new char[] { ' ', ',', '.' });
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; ++i){
  counter += keywords.Contains(words[i]) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

And you can do likewise for `sentence2`. Whoever gets the highest `counter` has the highest hits.

Answer (score 1):

This might be too advanced for a 1st year student but this piece of code will work for your need. Using [Regex](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex) class to do matching for you. Performance-wise it's faster (AFAIK). I used a console application to work on this as I don't think it will be hard for you to use it in a WinForms/WPF application.

```
            string textBoxInput = "car test do bmw"; // Just a sample as I am using a console app
            string[] sentences = File.ReadAllLines("sentences.txt"); // Read all lines of a text file and assign it to a string array
            string[] keywords = textBoxInput.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // Split textBoxInput by space
            int[] matchArray = new int[sentences.Length];

            for(int i = 0; i < sentences.Length; i++)
            {
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b(" + string.Join("|", keywords.Select(Regex.Escape).ToArray()) + @"+\b)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(sentences[i]);
                matchArray[i] = matches.Count;
            }

            int highesMatchIndex = Array.IndexOf(matchArray, matchArray.OrderByDescending(item => item).First());

            Console.WriteLine("User input: " + textBoxInput);
            Console.WriteLine("Matching sentence: " + sentences[highesMatchIndex]);
            Console.WriteLine("Match count: " + matchArray[highesMatchIndex]);

            Console.ReadLine();
```